# How to pass multiple keywords to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this Stored Procedure which returns records containing the specified keyword.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SearchKeywordPaged](
    @KeyWordFilter varchar(50)
    ,@PageNumber int = 1)      

as
begin

declare @PageSize int = 50
declare @FirstRow int
declare @LastRow int
declare @TotalRows int

SELECT      @FirstRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1,
            @LastRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + @PageSize;

select @TotalRows =      COUNT(*) from 
    [Quotes] q inner join [Keywords] k 
    ON q.id = k.Quoteid where k.Keyword = @KeyWordFilter;

with Results as
(                  
    SELECT            
        q.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (Order By Author asc) as Instance_Count
        ,@TotalRows as the_Count
    FROM [Quotes] q
    INNER JOIN [Keywords] k ON q.id = k.Quoteid
    WHERE k.Keyword = @KeyWordFilter
)            

select      *
from      results
where      Instance_Count between @FirstRow and @LastRow
order by Instance_Count asc

end
```

How can I modify this stored procedure to accept more than 1 keyword for search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that convertes a string into a table. You can use the example below:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_SplitString]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]
GO
CREATE   FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]    (@xStr varchar(8000))
RETURNS @out table (
    x varchar(500))  AS  
begin

declare @lp int set @lp=1
declare @xlen int
set @xlen=len(@xstr)

declare @xchar char(1)
declare @thisSplit varchar(50)
set @thisSplit=''

while @lp <= @xlen
 begin
    set @xchar=substring(@xstr,@lp,1)

    set @thisSplit=@thisSplit + @xchar

        if (@xchar=',') or (@lp=@xlen)
         begin
            insert into @out (x) values (replace(@thisSplit,',',''))
            set @thisSplit=''
         end
    set @lp=@lp+1   
 end


RETURN  
end
GO
select X from fn_SplitString('aaa,bbb,cccc')
```

Then, modify the `WHERE` clause of your stored procedure like this:

```
WHERE k.Keyword in (select x from fn_SplitString(@KeyWordFilter) )
```

Finally, you can use your SP passing a list of keywords as a comma separated list, like this:

```
exec [SearchKeywordPaged]  @KeyWordFilter='keyword1,keyword2,...'
```

Comment: I don't know well sql, an example based on my stored procedure would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Answered edited to include an example of the function. In your SP you just need to change the "where" clause.

Comment: If I modify the where clause, I get this error: Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SearchKeywordsPaged, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: The second where clause works, only the first which counts the total records is not working

Comment: the function does not return any record.

Comment: Run the function directly to make sure of that. For example:

    declare @KeyWordFilter varchar(50) = 'word 1,word 2,word 3'
    select X from fn_SplitString(@KeyWordFilter)

should return a table with 3 records.

Comment: Yes directly works, probably it was my mistake. I have searched for 'make,movie' but it returns rows which contains only one of the keyword or both, I need the select to contain all keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do something dynamic in your stored procedure.  For example:

```
declare @keywords varchar(50);
declare @sql  varchar(256);

-- @keywords is defined locally here, but it would be passed into your proc.
-- these are all single quotes.
select @keywords = ' ''keyword1'', ''keyword2'', ''keyword3'' '

select @sql = 'select * from a_table where keyword in (' + @keywords + ')'
exec(@sql)
```